# Openshift doesn't perform syncdb on push

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have the following error when performing my pushes and app-restart:

```
remote: Executing 'python /var/lib/openshift/6783687678687678/app-root/runtime/repo//wsgi/openshift/manage.py syncdb --noinput' 

remote: python: can't open file '/var/lib/openshift/6783687678687678/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/openshift/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However this is not the path of my app. I cannot find out where the settings are so that I can change them to the actual path. I've tried: `setup.py, settings, application` and none of these seem to relate to the above path. The path should be:

```
/var/lib/openshift/6783687678687678/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/mycoolapp/manage.py'
```

If I change the path in the action_hooks i.e. deploy, I get the following:

```
Executing 'python /var/lib/openshift/6783687678687678/app-root/runtime/repo//wsgi/app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/var/lib/app/6783687678687678/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/app/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:     from django.core.management import execute_manager
remote: ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [cartridge docs](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.html):

> For backward compatibility, the wsgi/application path is selected as default WSGI entry-point > with higher priority. You can customize the path using the OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION > environment variable.

But it looks like your application is in the right path so, I would check your action_hooks in the repo under `~/.openshift/action_hooks/` to see if there are some custom actions defined.

Comment: @niharvery I changed this, if I do I get the error that I posted above. The path should be correct. I get the same error if I try python manage direct.